# A inequality about pointwise absolute value vectors

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete group and $\xi\in l^{2}(\Gamma)$ be a unit vector. If $|\xi|$ be the pointwise absolute value of $\xi$, then how to verify: ($S$ is a linear bounded operator on $l^{2}(\Gamma)$)
$$|\langle S\xi, \xi\rangle|\leq\langle S|\xi|, |\xi|\rangle?$$
I suppose the pointwise absolute value of $\xi$ means: if $\xi=\{(x_{i})_{i\in \Gamma}: \sum\limits_{i\in \Gamma}|x_{i}|^{2}<\infty\}$, then $|\xi|=\{(|x_{i}|)_{i\in \Gamma}: \sum\limits_{i\in \Gamma}|x_{i}|^{2}<\infty\}$.

Comment: What is $S$? $ $

Comment: @Martin Argerami Oh, it is a linear bounded operator on $l^{2}(\Gamma)$. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That inequality is not true. Let $\Gamma=\mathbb Z_2$, so $\ell^2(\Gamma)=\mathbb C^2$. Take
$$
\xi=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix},\ \ S=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $S|\xi|=0$ and $\langle S|\xi|,|\xi|\rangle=0$, while
$$
\langle S\xi,\xi\rangle=\left\langle\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle=2
$$

**Edit:** even when $S$ is positive the inequality fails. You have
$$
\langle S\xi,\xi\rangle=\left\langle\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle=\left\langle\begin{bmatrix}2\\-2\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle=4,
$$
$$
\langle S|\xi|,|\xi|\rangle=\left\langle\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle=\left\langle\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle=0.
$$

Comment: If I add the assumption that $S$ is self-adjoint and norm-one, can we get the inequality?

Comment: No. The norm is irrelevant.  And you can take $S=\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix} $, with the same $\xi$.

Comment: Oh, is there anything wrong in my  comprehension of "pointwise absolute value of $\xi$"? Er...

Comment: I don't know. Please see the edit.